# kotlin Socket connection regularly sends but does not receive data

Tags: python, android, kotlin, sockets, networking

I'm trying to write an application with a server in python.
Everything is perfectly connected and the strings are sent from android, but it is not possible to get a string from the server. When trying to get a string, the stream is simply blocked, and if you set a timeout, then exception "timeout" is simply called, which is logical. I've tried everything, I'll show you at once all the code for both sending and receiving that I've come to at the moment (BufferedReader().ready() at the same time, everything works perfectly)

**pythonServer**

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(server_address)
server_socket.listen(1)

print ('Waiting for a client connection...')
connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print ('Connected to:', client_address)


# listen for data for forever
while True:
    data = connection.recv(data_size)
    print ('Received', data.decode('utf-8')) # print as raw bytes
    sizeOfMainMsg = int(data.decode('utf-8'))
    data = connection.recv(sizeOfMainMsg)
    print ('Received', data.decode('utf-8')) # print as raw bytes
    toSendTry = "Sendet "
    connection.send(bytes(toSendTry,'UTF-8'))
```

**KotlinClient**

```
clientSocket = Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT)


clientSocketOut = clientSocket!!.getOutputStream()
clientSocketIn = clientSocket!!.getInputStream()

if (clientSocket != null) {
while (clientSocketOut != null && clientSocketIn != null && clientSocket!!.isConnected()) {
    var tmp = clientSocketIn!!.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8)
    if(tmp.ready()){
        recived.add(tmp.readLine()) #This is where the problems occur
    }
    if (toSend.size > 0){
        for (nowMsg in toSend){
            clientSocketOut!!.write(nowMsg.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8).size.toString().toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
            clientSocketOut!!.flush()
            clientSocketOut!!.write(nowMsg.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
            clientSocketOut!!.flush()
        }
        toSend.clear()
    }
}
```

(Needless to say, the kotlin client code is written in AsyncTask)

Comment: Where is the python server running? On a pc? And you have a client app running on an Android device?

Comment: Your client tries to read a line. Now in order to succeed the server should have sent a line. Is the server doing that? A line is NOT just a string.

Comment: The server is currently running on a PC. Through wifi, there is a connection to an android device. the catch is that the server connects and receives a message from the android device stably and without errors. But what is sent from the server to the device is not received. To be precise, buffer.ready() becomes true, but everything just stops at .readLine(). The server regularly sends. By the way, yes, I did not specify exactly a little - I am sending an array of bytes received from the string

Comment: `Through wifi, there is a connection to an android device.`  ?? A client app on the Android device can connect to your server on the pc is what can happen.

Comment: `the catch is that the server connects` No. A client can start a connection. The server is not connecting. It listens until a client connects.

Comment: `everything just stops at .readLine().` Well if the receiver tries to read a line then the sender should have sent one. Now what did the sender sent? A line? You know that not every string is a line? I told you that already in my second comment but you did not react on it. Why?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand very well. And thank you for continuing to help. The server sends the "Sender" translated into a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client tries to read a line.

Now in order to succeed the server should have sent a line.

A line is NOT just a string.

Have a look at  `newline character`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been working on this for several weeks. It's finally working.